# Laravel: How to get multiple records

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, declaration

I want to have multiple records in my subject table, but it keeps getting only the last record of my sections table.

Im fetching the records according to the selected dropbox(sections) and in that dropdown it will fetch what's inside that table.

**Here's my Controller**

```
public function subjectCreate(){
    $users1 = [];
    $sections = [];
    $users1 = User::where('isTeacher', '1')->where('isAdmin', '0')->lists('firstname','id');
    $sections = Section1::lists('name','name');
    return View::make('teacher.create_subject', compact('users1','sections')
    );
}

public function subjectStore(){
    $validate = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'name' => 'required|unique:subject'
        ));
    if ($validate->fails()){
        return Redirect::route('subjectCreate')->withErrors($validate)->withInput();
    } else {
        foreach(Section1::where('name', '=',  Input::get('section_name'))->get() as $section)
        foreach(User::where('id', '=', Input::get('teacher_id'))->get() as $teacher)
        $teacher_id = Input::get('teacher_id');
        $subject = new Subject1();
        $subject->name = Input::get('name');
        $subject->student_id = $section->student_id;   
        $subject->student_firstname = $section->student_firstname;  
        $subject->student_lastname = $section->student_lastname;   
        $subject->teacher_id = $teacher_id;
        $subject->teacher_firstname = $teacher->firstname;  
        $subject->teacher_lastname = $teacher->lastname;
        $subject->section_id = $section->id;
        $subject->section_name = $section->name;
        $subject->save();
    }
    return Redirect::route('viewSubject')->with('success', 'SUBJECT HAS BEEN RECORDED!');
}
```

**Here are my dropdowns**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('teacher_name', 'Assign a Teacher to this subject:') }}
    {{ Form::select('teacher_id', $users1, null) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('section_name', 'Assign a Section to this subject:') }}
    {{ Form::select('section_name', $sections, null) }}
</div>
```

Comment: Few things of note: You shouldn't need to define `$users1` or `sections` as arrays before passing them to the view, that seems redundant. What are you doing with those `foreach()` loops? Also is this Laravel 4 or 5? You have tags for both but they aren't the same...

Comment: im using laravel 4, 
in the foreach loops its getting the data that has that condition as students in the Section table

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the curly braces on the inner `foreach`.

So your code here

```
foreach(User::where('id', '=', Input::get('teacher_id'))->get() as $teacher)
$teacher_id = Input::get('teacher_id');
$subject = new Subject1();
...
```

Is equivalent to the snippet below. Thus, only 1 subject per section is saved.

```
foreach(User::where('id', '=', Input::get('teacher_id'))->get() as $teacher) {
    $teacher_id = Input::get('teacher_id');
}
$subject = new Subject1();
...
```

Here's the code that should go in the `else` block.

```
foreach(Section1::where('name', '=',  Input::get('section_name'))->get() as $section) {
    foreach(User::where('id', '=', Input::get('teacher_id'))->get() as $teacher) {
        $teacher_id = Input::get('teacher_id');
        $subject = new Subject1();
        $subject->name = Input::get('name');
        $subject->student_id = $section->student_id;   
        $subject->student_firstname = $section->student_firstname;  
        $subject->student_lastname = $section->student_lastname;   
        $subject->teacher_id = $teacher_id;
        $subject->teacher_firstname = $teacher->firstname;  
        $subject->teacher_lastname = $teacher->lastname;
        $subject->section_id = $section->id;
        $subject->section_name = $section->name;
        $subject->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: its still getting only one record :( ,  however it gets the first column of the student in that section :)

Comment: How are you getting it?